# Unable to run ElasticSearch as a service on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, service, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get ElasticSearch up and running following the normal [setup guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2010/07/01/setting-up-elasticsearch.html).

Everything is running fine on my Macbook but I'm trying to do the same on an Ubuntu 11.04 server.

Running `/usr/local/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -f` works and I get a response from `curl http://localhost:9200`.

However this is what I get when I try to start ElasticSearch as a service (I've installed the service wrapper):

```
$ rcelasticsearch start

Starting ElasticSearch...
Waiting for ElasticSearch.............................
WARNING: ElasticSearch may have failed to start.
```

Sure enough `rcelasticsearch status` says `ElasticSearch is not running` and localhost:9200 cannot be reached.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Edit:
The service log says:

```
Launching a JVM...
JVM exited while loading the application.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Comment: Does the elasticsearch user have write permissions to data and logs directories of your elasticsearch installation? Is there anything in the log file?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The server instance didn't have enough memory for the default ElasticSearch service wrapper settings.  To fix this I edited `/usr/local/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch.conf` and changed `ES_HEAP_SIZE` from 1024 to 512

Comment: Thanks a lot and my config is at /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch.conf

Comment: For debian look at `/etc/default/elasticsearch`. According to the start script, `ES_HEAP_SIZE` sets both min and max allocated memory, so that the JVM does not have to increase the reserved space at runtime.

Comment: I tried to edit my /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch.conf, but it didn't work

Comment: I wish there were a more informative error message somewhere.

Comment: Didnt work. any other solution?