# Elasticsearch may have failed to start on CentOS

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, centos6

I have just installed elasticsearch on my CentOS 6.5 server. However When i run the following commands, saw failure message. I have also edited HEAP_SIZE like this link [Unable to run ElasticSearch as a service on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815392/unable-to-run-elasticsearch-as-a-service-on-ubuntu/10816527#10816527)

```
[root@CentOS /]# rcelasticsearch start
Starting Elasticsearch...
Waiting for Elasticsearch...............................
WARNING: Elasticsearch may have failed to start.
[root@CentOS /]#

[root@CentOS /]# /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
Starting Elasticsearch...
Waiting for Elasticsearch...............................
WARNING: Elasticsearch may have failed to start.
[root@CentOS /]#
```

**Here is service.log:**

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:20:47 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 64-bit 3.5.14
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:20:47 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2011 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:20:47 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:20:47 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 | WrapperSimpleApp Error: Unable to locate the class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/02 10:20:48 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:20:50 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 | WrapperSimpleApp Error: Unable to locate the class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 | 
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 | 
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/05/02 10:20:54 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:20:56 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 | WrapperSimpleApp Error: Unable to locate the class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 | 
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 | 
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/05/02 10:21:01 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:03 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 | WrapperSimpleApp Error: Unable to locate the class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 | 
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 | 
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/05/02 10:21:07 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:09 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 | WrapperSimpleApp Error: Unable to locate the class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 | 
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 | 
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/02 10:21:14 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:16 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:16 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:16 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/05/02 10:21:16 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

**How can i fix this problem?**

Comment: Have you tried reinstall???

Comment: @BlackPOP yes, i have tried again and again

Comment: do a thing,download ES tar file and start manually..  https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.1.1.tar.gz

Comment: I have already appliead wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.90.1.zip commands and elasticsearch is installed. but elasticsearch cannot down as see question. let me say is wget command invalid?

Comment: downloaded tar and untar it and start using ./elasticsearch??

Comment: @BlackPOP sure, i did

Comment: PLSEASE POST THE LOGS WHEN YOU STARTED MANUALLY..!

Comment: Have you tried installing the rpm from elasticsearch? Works great for me on centos 6.5 with openjdk 1.7. It comes with proper init.d scripts. You may want to remove the cruft you've accumulated with previous attempts to install elasticsearch.

Comment: @JillesvanGurp i have tried many installing method for the elasticsearch configuration. Finally i can configure elastichsearch which is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it:

```
yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk*
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the es version you are using. I think you are using old service to run es try to get new service from github and start the elasticsearch , It may solve your problem.